# OpenCV methods to detect uncut rows border in the agriculture field

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

For [agricultural field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HvgD.jpg)
i use [calcOpticalFlowFarneback](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html) methhod to recieve this

[image: grayscale]

image from an image sequence, it seems very robust.

But I have trouble with next steps - to find cut/uncut grass field borderline.
AdaptiveThreshold, erote and dilate methods don't provides me good results and don't seems reliable on video feed - maybe i just messed up with parameters:

```
adaptiveThreshold(grayFrame, bw, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 1);
Mat verticalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(1, 2));
erode(bw, bw2,  verticalStructure, Point(-1,-1),3);
dilate(bw, bw2, verticalStructure, Point(-1,-1),3);
Mat structuringElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(2, 4));
morphologyEx( bw2, bw2, MORPH_CLOSE, structuringElement, Point(-1,-1), 3);
```

[image: result img]

Should I try another approach such as neural networks, Kalman filters, or can I receive results from my first step - grayscale image?

Answer (score 1):

"""Should i try another approach such as neural networks, Kalman filters, or can can i receive result from my first step - grayscale image?"""

**answer**  Yes, I would try another approach. This is the type of thing that neural nets have been doing quite well on. There are several "out of the box" pretrained segmentation networks (try a U-net first) that will give you a head start.
You will need to:

-use a bunch of images to create your labeled data: create a mask over the un-harvested areas.

-"finetune" the net with your data. [keras finetuning documentation](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/)

Of course, as with any such problem, you may run into other hurdles like:

-how big of images/crops to use

-how to predict a whole image

-and, most of all, assuming you can perfectly mask the un-cut areas of your field images, does your problem *actually get solved*?  The exercise I always do is to pretend I have a black box that will give me my perfect results (in your case, a nice binary mask)...then complete the entire task downstream of that. If it solves the problem then it's worth spending time doing the machine learning...and if not, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Thank's you for great advice, i think it's definitely worth it. We work on big harvester manufacturer company, and have many new interesting tasks - this is one of them, part of agriculture autopilot development. But our team is very small, we have lack of experience in computer vision. We can't afford more experienced developers now because of bureaucracy. One thing i worry about - lack of data and time for network training, this is why i tried non-dnn approach. So it's basically an effort to develop fast prototype to approve viability of the project